# Write each individual row of a csv as a separate list (python)

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file and with 8 rows each with many columns and I want to turn each row into a new list so that I end up with a total of 8 different lists each storing one row of information from the CSV. This seems like it should be really simple but I can't work out how to do it :/ any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and look at the [tour] and even [mcve], a minimum courtesy is to show what you have tried in solving your problem.

Comment: I should end up with 8 lists and then pick one random item from each list and so end up with 8 random words but with exactly one from each row

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It could be as simple as

```
from csv import reader
from random import choice

with open(myfile, newline="") as in_f:
    rd = csv.reader(in_f)
    choices = [choice(row) for row in rd]
```

(no need to make individual lists)

Comment: I did run into a slight problem, the lengths of each row are not the same so occasionally a blank is stored instead of one of the words in the shorter rows, do you know of any quick fixes for this?

Comment: Edit the .csv file so it doesn't have blank cells at the end of any rows? (ie if you open it in a text editor, make sure there are no commas at the end of a line).